# How to implement try_pop() method in queue in c++?

Tags: c++, queue

Below is queue example in "C++ concurrency in action 2nd".
This example is single threaded queue, which will be modified to explain thread safe.

```
template<typename T>
class queue {
 private:
  struct node {
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    node(T data_) : data(std::move(data_)) {}
  };
  std::unique_ptr<node> head;
  node* tail;
 public:
  queue() : tail(nullptr) {};
  queue(const queue& other) = delete;
  queue& operator=(const queue& other) = delete;

  std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop() {
    if (!head) return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(head->data)));
    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(old_head->next);
    if(!head) tail = nullptr;
    return res;
  }

  void push(T new_value) {
    std::unique_ptr<node> p(new node(std::move(new_value)));
    node* const new_tail = p.get();
    if(tail) {
      tail->next = std::move(p);
    } else {
      head = std::move(p);
    }
    tail = new_tail;
  }
};
```

I can understand this queue works fine, but the way try_pop() is implemented seems to be weird.
Is it better way to do like below ?

```
  std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop() {
    if (!head) return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(head->data)));

//    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head = std::move(head);
//    head = std::move(old_head->next);

    head = std::move(head->next);

    if(!head) tail = nullptr;
    return res;
  }
```

Why head should be copied to old_head on this?
Is there any reason I missed?

Comment: The evaluation and assignment of `head` and `tail` is anything-but thread-safe. This is a recipe for race conditions run amok.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I edit my question. This example is for single-threaded queue. But my question is still same.

Comment: Yeah, we need some context, the only way I would see this code appearing in "C++ cuncurrency in action" is in the section "how not to do it"

Comment: This example is single threaded queue, which will be modified to explain thread safe later in this book

Comment: The behavior your eliminating is to ensure the lifetime of the old head lasts until the new head is established by moving out of `head->next`. Without that you run into a condition where the reset of `head` prior to the hitching to `head->next` will, in fact, destroy it (and subsequently `head->next`, in the process). In other words, de-hitching `head->next` from `head` prior to `head` being destroyed is paramount. This isn't the only way to do it, but it is one option.

Comment: The author may be concerned that `head = std::move(head->next);` will cause the instance owned by `head` and consequently the one owned by `head->next` to be destroyed during the assignment, but I believe that the standard requires the instance pointed by `next` be released before `head` is destroyed, so it should behave properly.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  If the condition you said is concerned, std::move(old_head->next); looks have same situation. old_head->next can be destroyed during the assignment. Is it really matter on single threaded queue?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa If you move `head` to `old_head` then `head == nullptr`. When you then do `head = std::move(old_head->next);` you move nothing is destroyed because `head` is `nullptr`. The actual old `head` is only destroyed when `old_head`'s lifetime ends at the end of the scope. So you are 100% sure that the value `head->next` had is never accidentally destroyed during `head = std::move(old_head->next);`. In your version, at first glance it is not apparent that `head->next` survives this assignment ...

Comment: @myoldgrandpa ...  If `head` were destroyed first during the assigment (to prepare to receive a new pointer value) then `head->next` may be destroyed before it can be transferred to `head`. Though I don't believe this is actually allowed to happen. But the fact that it raises questions means it is probably not a good design choice. The compiler will likely remove the extra move if it is not needed anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Very appreciated. I got your point. You mean head could be cleared and then assigned during assignment operator. I never think of this. Is it common situation that clear member variable before assign when assign operator?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa What I describe is the logic someone *might* use. In reality this doesn't happen. Internally `head->next` is **released** from that pointer and stored in a raw pointer momentarily just before `head` is destroyed, then the raw pointer is given to `head` so it should be safe to use the one line version. But, because the logic I described in my previous comment is something someone could easily come up with, using the one line version could cause confusion in the future. Someone else might not know how it works and ask the same question. So I think the two line version is better.